# Flutter desktop windows notification badge on app icon

Tags: flutter, desktop, badge

I can't seem to find this one. Is it possible to add the number on the app icon? (windows desktop)

For example this is Telegram on windows:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`package:windows_taskbar`](https://github.com/alexmercerind/windows_taskbar) to add badge (overlay icon) to your Flutter Windows app's taskbar icon.

You have to create icons yourself though, maybe "1", "2", "3"... "9" & "9+" like most applications (as `.ico` files).

It's very easy to use as well.

#### Add in pubspec.yaml

```dart
dependencies:
  windows_taskbar: ^1.1.0
```

#### Set Icon

```dart
WindowsTaskbar.setOverlayIcon(
  ThumbnailToolbarAssetIcon('assets/red_slash.ico'),
  tooltip: 'Stop',
);
```

Don't forget to add the icon file to your `pubspec.yaml` assets.

#### Remove Icon

```dart
WindowsTaskbar.resetOverlayIcon();
```

**NOTE**: I'm developer of the package.

[image: windows_taskbar]

Answer (score 1):

These badges are autocreated on notification. There arent much packages for notifications in windows. You can give [this](https://pub.dev/packages/quick_notify) a try.

quick_notify: ^0.2.1

```
QuickNotify.notify(
  title: 'My title',
  content: 'My content',
);
```

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't create the number badge. Just a notification. I only need the number badge on top of my app icon. Thanks anyway.